# Skip authorize resource in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, authorization

I'm trying to make the user profiles in a project I'm working on viewable by anyone on the web, so I tried adding `skip_authorize_resource :only => [:show]` to the user controller and the user model.  However, when I visit `/users/1` nothing happens and I'm prompted to login when I add it to the controller; when I add it to the model, i get an error message:

```
undefined method `skip_authorize_resource'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `authenticate_user` method for devise

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :show
```

or you can use

```
 check_authorization
```

method in controller

like this way

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  check_authorization :unless => :do_not_check_authorization?

   private
   def do_not_check_authorization?
     ...
   end
 end
```